# How to create toolbars for other pages apart from the main page in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am creating an app with multiple pages, I was able to create a toolbar for the Main Page, but for the second page toolbar is not showing. I need help?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SIS_Song_Book.SettingsPage" Title="Settings">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="sync" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I tried fiddling with the app.xml.cs page but with no success.

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SIS_Song_Book
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

            SettingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what it looks like and what you would like it to look like. This code: `SettingsPage = new NavigationPage(new SettingsPage());` shouldn't even compile unless you added a `SettingsPage` property to the `App` class (which you probably shouldn't).